# How to load JS sdk into the browser?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am looking at the docs here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/

Having enormous trouble figuring out how to install it via webpack or using a script tag. How do I get the Facebook JS SDK in the browser? Why so hard to figure out given the docs? Am I stupid?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind it's just bad documentation, to load the sdk using a script tag, it's here:

```html
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'your-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.2'
    });
  };
</script>
<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

yep that second script tag is how.

Comment: what do you mean with bad documenation? that code is right there in the link you posted...? - you can also just load it with javascript, by adding the script tag dynamically.